# x_input=numpy.array(), TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer, lstm

I am running the python code and facing that error. I am trying to resolve it but I couldn't because I am not familiar with python. So, guide me and suggest a proper solution. I want to calculate the Dissimilarity Score from two Results respectively with and without GAN.
Here is the part of the code which has an issue:

```
raw_seq = class_instances[:,1]
n_steps = len(class_instances1[:,1])
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps)

n_features = 1
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, verbose=0)
model.summary()
x_input = class_instances1[:,1]
x_input = numpy.array(n_steps[6:13])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print("\n Result:", yhat, "\n")
```

This is the output:

```
Mean Feature Representation (MFR) : 74.47619047619048
Difference of each activity with MFR: 
 [42.47619047619048, 40.47619047619048, -120.52380952380952, -39.52380952380952, -185.52380952380952, 51.47619047619048, 24.47619047619048, 50.47619047619048, -69.52380952380952, 54.47619047619048, 9.476190476190482, 64.47619047619048, -25.52380952380952, 54.47619047619048, 53.47619047619048, -71.52380952380952, 33.47619047619048, 23.47619047619048, 57.47619047619048, -2.5238095238095184, -45.52380952380952]
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_10 (LSTM)               (None, 50)                10400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 10,451
Trainable params: 10,451
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\thesis code\TC_code.py", line 102, in <module>
    x_input = numpy.array(n_steps[6:13])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `n_steps` is an `int` object declared with `n_steps = len(class_instances1[:,1])` so you can't use indexing over it as `n_steps[6:13]` and therefore the error.

Comment: What were you trying to do with that line?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Give an array to reshape and then calculate the Dissimilarity Score. After this apply Generative Adversarial Network and in the end LSTM.

Comment: That's what you're trying to do in the code in general. What's the purpose of that specific line? The more I look at it, the less it makes sense.

Comment: Often in questions like this it is hard to tell what code you've borrowed from some tutorial or other example, and what you've written yourself.  Especially when you claim to be new to Python, but have relatively advanced code (using `Sequential`).  What ever your intentions, the `n_steps[6:13]` expression is a basic Python error.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you may use indices only on iterable objects (e.g., `lists`, `numpy.arrays` etc.).
As the error states, in the following line:

`x_input = numpy.array(n_steps[6:13])`

you try to index `n_steps` variable , which is an `int` and comes from `n_steps = len(class_instances1[:,1])`, which is not permitted.

Cheers

Comment: So, what would I use instead of n_steps variable. What's your suggestion?

Comment: what is the purpose of this line?

Comment: Give an array to reshape and then calculate the Dissimilarity Score.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the unknown data is located in `raw_seq`, so I could guess that you'd need to replace  `n_steps[6:13]` with `raw_seq[6:13]`, but again, it's only my guess, because I don't really know what is the desired outcome of your code.

Comment: Give an array for reshaping and then calculate the Dissimilarity Score. After this, apply Generative Adversarial Network and in the end LSTM. This is the desired target.